# How do I preview a PDF document link on Chrome Android like I do on the chrome on a computer?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Whenever we open a PDF document link on a computer browser, we have a preview and then we decide if we want to download. But, when using a smartphone browser, the file is downloaded automatically. How to have a PDF preview inside the android browser?

Comment: [See the issue log to know why it's not possible](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/68561173/android-chrome-browser-don-t-preview-pdf?hl=en&msgid=68582076) Quote *"The Android Chrome Browser APP doesn't support plug-ins, so it doesn't have a Chrome PDF Viewer. There for a PDF file  can't natively be read without install a PDF APP on the Android Device.
 
You might try using the Google PDF viewer on the Android device."*
 Unquote

Comment: Simple, if slightly facetious, answer - use a better browser.